# QRCode displaying in tkinter GUI python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, qr-code

I am trying to display a QR Code in a tkinter GUI, however when I execute this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import pyqrcode
from tkinter.font import Font
import random


root=tk.Tk()
root.title("QR Lottery")
root.config(bg="white")

# Defining Fonts
TitleFont = Font(family="HEX:gon Staggered 2", size="48")

def generateQR():
    num=random.randint(1,2)
    if num==1:
        QRCode=pyqrcode.create("You Win!")
        QRCode.png("QRCode.png",scale=8)
        img = Image.open('QRCode.png')
        QRCodeImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        QRCodeLabel=tk.Label(image=QRCodeImg)
        QRCodeLabel.grid(row=2,column=1)
    else:
        QRCode=pyqrcode.create("You Lose!")
        QRCode.png("QRCode.png",scale=8)
        img = Image.open('QRCode.png')
        QRCodeImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        QRCodeLabel=tk.Label(image=QRCodeImg)
        QRCodeLabel.grid(row=2,column=1)

#Labels
TitleLabel=tk.Label(text="qr lottery",bg="white",font=TitleFont)
TitleLabel.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=5)
ButtonQR=tk.Button(text="Generate!",bg="white",command=generateQR)
ButtonQR.grid(row=3,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The Image Label produced is a blank square. I am unsure of why this is, as I left the background color blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a png file from a webpage on a tk label in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562771/how-to-display-a-png-file-from-a-webpage-on-a-tk-label-in-python)

Comment: again problem with bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory and you can see only empty square. Read doc: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: @norok2 Not a dupe, as I have followed the answer you provided and It has not yielded the desired result.

Comment: For your case, simply add `generateQR.img = QRCodeImg` at the end of `generateQR()` function body in order to keep a reference of the image.  However, it is not recommended to recreate the QR label every time the generate button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: The Image Label produced is a blank square. I am unsure of why this is
>
> **A**:You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, by attaching it to another object.

## Use the following:

---

1. Define your own widget `QRCodeLabel` by inherit from `tk.Label`.
   Init only with parameter `parent`

   ```
   class QRCodeLabel(tk.Label):
       def __init__(self, parent, qr_data):
           super().__init__(parent)
           print('QRCodeLabel("{}")'.format(qr_data))
   ```
2. Create your `QRCode` with the passed `qr_data` and
   save as `PNG` file.

   ```
           qrcode = pyqrcode.create(qr_data)
           tmp_png_file = "QRCode.png"
           qrcode.png(tmp_png_file, scale=8)
   ```
3. Create a image object from the `PNG` file.
   Tkinter can handle `PNG` image files by its own, no `PIL` needed.

   > **NOTE**: You have to use `self.image` to prevent garbage collection!

   ```
           self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=tmp_png_file)
   ```
4. Configure this `Label` with the `self.image`

   ```
           self.configure(image=self.image)
   ```

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
> class App(tk.Tk):
>     def __init__(self):
>         super().__init__()
>
>         buttonQR = tk.Button(text="Generate!", bg="white", command=self.generateQR)
>         buttonQR.grid(row=2, column=0)
>         self.qr_label = None
>
>     def generateQR(self):
>         if self.qr_label:
>             self.qr_label.destroy()
>
>         self.qr_label = QRCodeLabel(self, random.choice(["You Win!", "You Lose!"]))
>         self.qr_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     App().mainloop()
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***